# how to return int value from select query in function?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to retrieve Ticket_Id from tbl_Ticket to pass into body section of sending email function..
Is the below code correct?
every times i get Ticket_Id 1..

```
public int select_TicketId(){
    string strConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    string getId = ("select Ticket_Id from tbl_Ticket where Client_EmailAdd='" + objNewTic_BAL.email + "' ");
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(getId, sqlCon);
    int i=cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are searching for ExecuteScalar which returns the first value.

```
using System.Configuration;
//
public int select_TicketId()
    {
       string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strConn);
       string getId = ("select TOP 1 Ticket_Id from tbl_Ticket where Client_EmailAdd='" + objNewTic_BAL.email + "' ");
       sqlCon.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(getId, sqlCon);
       return Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
    }
```

*Also use CommandProperties to set the where statement for better security, like below:*

```
public int select_TicketId()
{
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    int result = -1;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "select TOP 1 Ticket_Id from tbl_Ticket where Client_EmailAdd=@email";
        command.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.Text).Value = objNewTic_BAL.email;
        result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call `int i=(int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();` method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `ExecuteNonQuery`. But it's a query. This should have rung some warning bells :)

Try [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead, and cast the result to int...

```
return (int) cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

Note that you should use `using` statements for the command and connection as well, so that both are closed appropriately.

*And* (I hadn't spotted this before) you should **definitely** use parameterized SQL instead of including a value directly into your SQL. Otherwise you're open to [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)...

So something like:

```
private const string FetchTicketIdSql =
    "select Ticket_Id from tbl_Ticket where Client_EmailAdd = @Email";

public int FetchTicketId()
{
    // No need for ToString call...
    string connectionString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(connection, FetchTicketIdSql))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 
                bjNewTic_BAL.email;
            return (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

You should consider what you *want* to happen if there isn't exactly one result though...

Answer (score 0):

Hiral,
ExecuteNonQuery in

```
int i=cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

will return number of records that satisfy your query. In this case it is 1 (or 0 if there are no emails)

Try using ExecuteReader instead.